# Returning the next item in an array based on user input

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, iteration, user-input

I am requesting user input using read. I would like to match the input to an array, and if it matches, print the next item in the array.

For example:

```
echo "What day of the week is it?"
read day
for d in "$(week[@])" do
if [ "$d" == "$day" ]; then
echo "The next day of the week is ${week [d++]}."
fi
done
```

I would only like to print the very next day. (So if the user inputs 'Wednesday' I would like only 'Thursday' to be returned. With the script above only the day 'Monday' is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop over the array by index until you find the day and increase the index again after the loop.

```
week=(Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su)  # another Su at the end
read day

i=0
until [[ ${week[i]} == $day ]]; do
    let i++
done

echo ${week[++i]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
week=(Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat)

i=0
for str in ${week[@]}; do
  if [[ $str = "$day" ]]; then
         i=$(((i+1)%7))                #Get index 0 if day is saturday
         echo "Next day is ${week[i]}" 
        break 
    fi
     i=$((i+1)) 
done
```